# Efficient Approach to Order Vectors?

Tags: vectors, computational-complexity, binary

given $n$ binary victors which may include $\$$ sign like this: $101\$0111$

What's the most efficient algorithm to order those vectors in $nxn$ matrix such that in the main diagonal there is no $\$$ signs? (In case it's not possible then output "Not possible"?

There is a trivial solution in $O(n!)$ by checking all possible options to order them and validating each option. Is there a more efficient approach maybe in polynomial time?

Comment: Let $M$ be any matrix $n \times n$ such that $M_{i,j}\neq 0$ iff there is no dollar sign at the $j$-th position of the vector $i$. The goal is to find out whether there is a permutation $s$ such that the product of the  $M_{s(i),i}$ is non zero. So here’s an idea: put pairwise distinct primes in the nonzero entries, and compute the determinant ($O(n^3)$ operations, if we assume arithmetic operations are in constant time – an assumption that can of course be challenged but the worst-case scenario will still be polynomial). This determinant is nonzero iff your answer is yes.

Comment: @Aphelli my professor says if there is a polynomial solution for my problem then $P=NP$ so it seems your proof is wrong

Comment: Yes, my “prime” construction rather clearly does not work.

Comment: @Aphelli A sum of more than two relatively prime integers can be zero.

Comment: @aschepler: indeed, that was the glaring issue.

Comment: The wikipedia page “#P-completeness of 01-permanent” contains however the following excerpt: “One reason for interest in the computational complexity of the permanent is that it provides an example of a problem where constructing a single solution can be done efficiently but where counting all solutions is hard.” That’s what my solution was failing to do – but it suggests that making such an approach work does not necessarily imply P=NP. Your professor probably knows best, obviously.

Comment: Linked from there, seems like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm ought to work, and it would be $O(n^{2.5})$.